# Como conjugar divs en collapse Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Encontre este codigo de Collapse en bootstrap 4, en el cual oculto y muestro divs con dos botones.

```
<p>
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" name="p1" onclick="ocultar(this.name)" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
 Primer div
</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" name="p2" onclick="ocultar(this.name)" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample2" >
Segundo Div
</a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
1 div. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
 </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
 <div class="card card-body">
2 div. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
 </div>
</div>
```

el detalle es que estoy buscando de que cuando presione el boton del primer div, se oculte el segundo div. encontre esta manera:

```
  document.getElementById('collapseExample2').style.display = 'none';
```

si sale, pero al momento de mostrar un div y ocultar el otro como se distorsiona. me imagino que habra un codigo de Bootstrap 4 que haga que se vea tal y como actua el collapse.

Comment: Mira en https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/ también https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior (este mira más abajo del mismo) depende lo que quieras hacer

Comment: a que te refieres con "conjugar"?